# Прокрутить следующую страницу к верху при клике по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день!

Как прокрутить следующую страницу к верху при клике по ссылке? Нужен клик на одной странице, а исполнение на другой. То есть переход по ссылке со страницы #1 на страницу #2, затем, прокрутка вверх на странице #2.

Ожидаю вопрос: "Зачем это? Разве при переходе по ссылке ты не оказываешься сразу вверху страницы?" В моем случае это iframe. Прокрутив его вниз, ты жмешь на ссылку и попадаешь в тоже место на другой странице. Содержимое другой страницы в несколько раз меньше, чем у первой. Получается, что пользователь видит пустое пространство.

Comment: $(window).scrollTop(0);

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает в моем случае. https://js.do/code/165403